# How to set an .ajax() responseText to a variable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom, document

My question is how can I get the HTML of one page and store it in an object that I can later search through with jQuery methods to get elements by id, name,class, etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button').click(function() {
        var page = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Grabber.php',
                data: {url:$('#url')},
                dataType: "HTML",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data); //this alert displays the correct information
                } 
                    }).responseText;
        alert(page); //this alert displays nothing
     });
  });
```

How can i get that "page" variable to work? And even better, how can I store it so I can access it as if it were an HTML document. My only idea so far is as a DOM document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var page;
 $('#button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Grabber.php',
            data: {url:$('#url')},
            dataType: "HTML",
            success: function(data){
                populate(data);
            } 
    });
    function populate(a) {
        page = a;
        alert(page)
        alert($(page).find('span').text())
    }

 });
});
```

Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), `$.ajax` returns `XMLHttpRequest` while the success method returns `data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest`. What you need here is the `data`
And to access it you can do something like:

```
$(page).find('span').text()
```

Comment: I have already tried this and the alert returns an "undefined"

Comment: The alert() can happen before the ajax-call has completed, resulting in an empty page variable. You need to work within the success function to be sure that the data is really there.

Comment: Put alert() inside the success function. alert() is being called before the HTTP request returns, so it's undefined. Either that, or set `async:  false` so that it waits for the HTTP request to return. But I'd recommend doing everything in the success function so other things aren't held up.

Comment: true fixed, in the success you can call your "search" function to get whatever you want just like in the updated example

Comment: this works correctly and is what i need, but if i ever need to do more ajax queries then it starts to get hairy with an ajax() within an ajax() within an ajax().

Comment: within? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The `data` in only available after a successful AJAX call. So any variable outside of this success function isn't necessarily set yet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'Grabber.php',
          data: {url:$('#url')},
          dataType: "HTML",
          success: function(data) {
            // keep working _within_ this function
            // and call it "page" instead of "data" if you want
            alert(data);

            // and to find something within this data:
            $(data).find('.some-class')... // etc
          } 
        });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your success callback you should assign a variable outside of it's local scope so that when the function ends, the data is not lost. Then you can pass it as the second parameter to the jQuery method to have your jQuery selector act on the AJAX-fetched document instead of the Document.

```
var a_nasty_global_variable_you_should_put_in_a_better_place;

// most of your code…

    success: function(data){
      a_nasty_global_variable_you_should_put_in_a_better_place = data;
    }

// a little later…

$('#button', a_nasty_global_variable_you_should_put_in_a_better_place).addClass('is-awesome');
```

You get the gist of it, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use **global variable** if you want that variable to be at same page where this ajax is present

**or**

You can use **cookies** to store your responseText if have to store some small amount of data and use responceText on other pages
for cookies with jquery [HELP?](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)